# How to echo multidimensional array using few codes?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have two scripts. One is named as index.php and other is home.php.

index.php is used for login (verification of username and password using in_array) and then redirecting user to home.php. Here is index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>


<body><center>

    <form method="POST" action="index.php" ">
        <h2>Log In</h2>
        Username: <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" placeholder="Your Username" maxlength="20"/><br/>
        Password: <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" maxlength="20"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_status" value="sent"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </form></center>

<?php

    $userdetails = array('james'=>'james123','john'=>'john123','stefan'=>'stefan123');

    if(isset($_POST['form_status']) && $_POST['form_status']=="sent"){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['password']= $_POST['password'];  


        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            if(in_array($_SESSION['password'],$userdetails)){
                header("location: home.php");
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Your password is incorrect";
        }


    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the second script (home.php), i have stored qualification and interests of users(in a multidimensional array) and then using that array to display the interest and qualification of loggedin user in home.php. Here is the script:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){

        $userdetails = array(
                        array("username"=>"james","qualification"=>"LLB from Harward.", "interests"=>"baseball, football and sports cars"),
                        array("username"=>"john","qualification"=>"Commerce.", "interests"=>"weight lifting, cars and cycling"),
                        array("username"=>"stefan","qualification"=>"MBBS.", "interests"=>"reading, photography and Gaming")
                        );              


            echo "Hello ". $_SESSION["username"];

                if($_SESSION['username']=="james"){
                    echo "<br/>Your qualification is ".$userdetails[0]['qualification'];
                    echo "<br/>Your interests are ".$userdetails[0]['interests'];
                    echo "<br/><a href='friends.php'>Your Friends</a><br/><a href='session_destroy.php'>Log Out</a><br/>";
                }

                if($_SESSION['username']=="john"){
                    echo "<br/>Your qualification is ".$userdetails[1]['qualification'];
                    echo "<br/>Your interests are ".$userdetails[1]['interests'];
                    echo "<br/><a href='friends.php'>Your Friends</a><br/><a href='session_destroy.php'>Log Out</a><br/>";
                }

                if($_SESSION['username']=="stefan"){
                    echo "<br/>Your qualification is ".$userdetails[2]['qualification'];
                    echo "<br/>Your interests are ".$userdetails[2]['interests'];
                    echo "<br/><a href='friends.php'>Your Friends</a><br/><a href='session_destroy.php'>Log Out</a><br/>";
                }



    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

Now the problem is that i have to write code for displaying qualification and interests of each user separately by using if else if statements.

Isnt is possible to use a single (or few statements) to display qualification and interest of a particular user to that user only?

PS. i know that it is recommended to use database for this purpose. I'm just practicing arrays and if elseif statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use a key-value array for the usernames:

```
$userdetails = array(
    "james" => array("username"=>"james","qualification"=>"LLB from Harward.", "interests"=>"baseball, football and sports cars"),
    "john" => array("username"=>"john","qualification"=>"Commerce.", "interests"=>"weight lifting, cars and cycling"),
    "stefan" => array("username"=>"stefan","qualification"=>"MBBS.", "interests"=>"reading, photography and Gaming")
);
```

Then you can just use the username as the key:

```
$details = $userdetails[$_SESSION['username']];
echo "<br/>Your qualification is ".$details['qualification'];
echo "<br/>Your interests are ".$details['interests'];
echo "<br/><a href='friends.php'>Your Friends</a><br/><a href='session_destroy.php'>Log Out</a><br/>";
```

Comment: and you could add the password to this array as well. then us it in an include file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` for `$userdetails`

```
   foreach($userdetails  as $k=>$userdetail){

     if($_SESSION['username']==$k){
         echo "<br/>Your qualification is ".$userdetail['qualification'];
         echo "<br/>Your interests are ".$userdetail['interests'];
         echo "<br/><a href='friends.php'>Your Friends</a><br/><a href='session_destroy.php'>Log Out</a><br/>";
     }

  }
```